# xSemaphoreTake won't resume a task after xSemaphoreGive has been called

Tags: c++, c++14, semaphore, freertos

I wanted to implement FreeRTOS Queue in C++ to be able to use C++ classes with the queue what is impossible with the standard FreeRTOS implementation of Queues.

The class looks like that:

```
template <typename T> class os_queue
{
  public:
    explicit os_queue(unsigned size);

    ~os_queue();

    template <typename U> bool send(U &&u);

    T receive(TickType_t timeout);

  private:
    std::vector<T> m_queue;
    const unsigned m_size;
    SemaphoreHandle_t m_mux;
    SemaphoreHandle_t m_queue_num_elems_sem;
};
```

The constructor and the destructor:

```
template <typename T> os_queue<T>::os_queue(unsigned size) : m_size(size)
{
    m_queue.reserve(size);
    m_mux = xSemaphoreCreateMutex();
    m_queue_num_elems_sem = xSemaphoreCreateCounting(size, 0);
}

template <typename T> os_queue<T>::~os_queue()
{
    vSemaphoreDelete(m_mux);
    vSemaphoreDelete(m_queue_num_elems_sem);
}
```

And the methods `send` and `receive` are implemented in such a way:

```
template <typename T> template <typename U> bool os_queue<T>::send(U &&u)
{
    static_assert(is_equiv<T, U>::value, "The argument must be of the same type as a queue element");

    bool is_full = false;

    {
        os_lockguard guard(m_mux);
        if (m_queue.size() == m_size)
            is_full = true;
        else
            m_queue.emplace_back(std::forward<U>(u));
    }

    if (!is_full)
        assert(xSemaphoreGive(m_queue_num_elems_sem) == pdTRUE);

    return !is_full;
}

template <typename T> T os_queue<T>::receive(TickType_t timeout)
{
    if (xSemaphoreTake(m_queue_num_elems_sem, timeout) == pdFALSE)
        throw std::runtime_error("Timeout when receiving element from the queue");
    else
    {
        os_lockguard guard(m_mux);
        auto res = std::move(m_queue[m_queue.size() - 1]);
        m_queue.pop_back();
        return res;
    }
}
```

`os_lockguard` on construction takes the mutex/semaphore using `xSemaphoreTake` and on destruction it calls `xSemaphoreGive` to release it.

The counting semaphore is used to control the number of the elements in the queue.

I wanted to test that solution and used [FreeRTOS port for Linux](https://github.com/michaelbecker/freertos-addons/).

To pass any function as a task code I created such a class:

```
class os_task
{
  public:
    template <typename TaskFuncType>
    os_task(TaskFuncType &&task_code, std::string name, unsigned short stack_size, UBaseType_t priority)
        : task_code(std::forward<TaskFuncType>(task_code))
    {
        if (xTaskCreate(
                [](void *p) {
                    auto os_task_p = static_cast<os_task *>(p);
                    os_task_p->task_code();
                    os_wait_indefinitely();
                },
                name.c_str(),
                stack_size,
                this,
                priority,
                &task_handle) != pdPASS)
            throw std::runtime_error("Could not create a task");
    }

    ~os_task() { vTaskDelete(task_handle); }

  private:
    TaskHandle_t task_handle;
    std::function<void(void)> task_code;
};
```

Using this class I wanted to test a simple case when there is one reader and one writer:

```
static void test_single_writer_single_reader()
{
    constexpr unsigned size = 16;
    os_queue<int> q(size);
    bool result_reader = false, result_writer = false;

    auto curr_task_handle = xTaskGetCurrentTaskHandle();
    os_task(std::bind(reader, std::ref(q), std::ref(result_reader), curr_task_handle), "reader", 128, 1);
    os_task(std::bind(writer, std::ref(q), std::ref(result_writer), curr_task_handle), "writer", 128, 1);

    try
    {
        wait_for_notifs(2);
    }
    catch (std::exception &e)
    {
        TEST_ASSERT_MESSAGE(false == true, e.what());
    }

    TEST_ASSERT(result_reader == true);
    TEST_ASSERT(result_writer == true);
}
```

This test is called from within a FreeRTOS task.

The reader and the writer takes a queue as a reference to call `send` and `receive` methods and a boolean variable to save a result of the operation somewhere:

```
static void reader(os_queue<int> &queue, bool &result, TaskHandle_t task_to_notify_at_end)
{
    int r;
    result = true;
    try
    {
        r = queue.receive(max_wait_time_ms);
    }
    catch (std::exception &e)
    {
        result = false;
    }
    xTaskNotifyGive(task_to_notify_at_end);
}

static void writer(os_queue<int> &queue, bool &result, TaskHandle_t task_to_notify_at_end)
{
    int v = 0;
    result = queue.send(v);
    xTaskNotifyGive(task_to_notify_at_end);
}
```

Finally `wait_for_notifs` is used to synchronize the task with the reader and the writer:

```
static void wait_for_notifs(BaseType_t notifs_num)
{
    while (notifs_num)
    {
        auto notifs = ulTaskNotifyTake(pdTRUE, portMAX_DELAY);
        if (notifs)
            notifs_num -= notifs;
        else
            throw std::runtime_error("Timeout when waiting for notifications");
    }
}
```

The main idea is that I want to check whether the application is able to handle races well.

The problem is that when the reader executes first and suspends on `xSemaphoreTask`, then the writer writes to the queue so it increments the sempahore's counter, the reader won't resume.

Shouldn't it work? The timeout in `xSemaphoreTake` exists to handle such situations well: when the semaphore is taken (its count is equal to 0) the function waits and hopes that other task can give (increment the counter) the semaphore.

Could it be related to port implementation or configuration?

I use FreeRTOS in version 9.0.0 with preemption and  time slicing enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
os_task(std::bind(reader, std::ref(q), std::ref(result_reader), curr_task_handle), "reader", 128, 1);
os_task(std::bind(writer, std::ref(q), std::ref(result_writer), curr_task_handle), "writer", 128, 1);
```

The created object is deleted just after it is constructed. Should be

```
os_task r(std::bind(reader, std::ref(q), std::ref(result_reader), curr_task_handle), "reader", 128, 1);
os_task w(std::bind(writer, std::ref(q), std::ref(result_writer), curr_task_handle), "writer", 128, 1);
```